# Get the file name of the included Jinja template that has error

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm trying to get the line number and file name of a Jinja template in which there is a syntax error.

For the moment, I've managed to get the line number with something like this:

```
        try:
            response = render_document_template(render_arguments)
        except TemplateError as error:
            line_number = error.lineno
            return Response(
                [str(error), line_number],
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

This works fine when working with templates that don't include other templates.

The problem comes when working with templates that do include other templates. I'm getting the line number of the included template, *BUT* I don't know in which of the several included templates the error is actually occurring.

So I get something like *there was a syntax error in line 10*. But it is of not much use, since I don't know to which included file that line number refers to.

So my question is, how can I know in which template is the error?